# How powerful is the smallest possible nuclear blast?

Tags: nuclear-physics, explosions

At the risk of drawing unwanted official attention to myself, I'm curious.  It is alleged that a tactical warhead had [little or no effect on six persons less than six kilometers away](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Plumbbob).

**What is the minimum "safe" distance from the weakest possible nuclear warhead?**  I am aware that they have to be designed so that criticality cannot occur until triggered, but I don't know the size or power of the minimum mass needed for an actual explosion.

Comment: I cannot, because I am not familiar with the latter term.  Perhaps a different edit will satisfy you.

Comment: The smallest possible nuclear "blast" (from a physics point of view) would be e.g. one nucleus struck by a neutron triggering fission.  I suspect you mean the smallest *weapon*, but there's no way of knowing how small a weapon could (in theory) be built and even then "safe" is relative.  "safe" in the middle of a flat countryside is different from "safe" in a city surrounded by potentially falling or propelled masonry and glass.